# Why does the proprietary nvidia driver break kernel dependencies?

Tags: fedora, kernel, nvidia, dnf

I'm running Fedora 25, with the following nvidia packages installed:

```
akmod-nvidia.x86_64                     1:375.26-1.fc25                 @rpmfusion-nonfree-updates
kmod-nvidia-4.8.12-300.fc25.x86_64.x86_64
kmod-nvidia-4.8.14-300.fc25.x86_64.x86_64
xorg-x11-drv-nvidia.x86_64              1:375.26-1.fc25                 @rpmfusion-nonfree-updates
xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-cuda.x86_64         1:375.26-1.fc25                 @rpmfusion-nonfree-updates
xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-kmodsrc.x86_64      1:375.26-1.fc25                 @rpmfusion-nonfree-updates
xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-libs.x86_64         1:375.26-1.fc25                 @rpmfusion-nonfree-updates
```

Whenever I run `dnf upgrade`, I get the following message:

```
Skipping packages with broken dependencies:
 kernel                                                       x86_64                                   4.8.15-300.fc25                                        updates                                         92 k
 kernel-core                                                  x86_64                                   4.8.15-300.fc25                                        updates                                         20 M
 kernel-modules                                               x86_64                                   4.8.15-300.fc25                                        updates                                         22 M
```

But if I remove all my nvidia packages, then I can run `dnf upgrade` no problem. I can install the nvidia packages again, after the kernel upgrade, no problem.

Why do the nvidia packages break kernel dependencies, and how can I stop that from happening?

Comment: [nVidia ...](http://makeagif.com/mI_U5W)

Answer (score 2):

It is most likely `kmod-nvidia` that is lagging behind.

You can either wait for the `kmod-nvidia` package for kernel 4.8.15 to be ready, or remove `kmod-nvidia-*` completely and let `akmod-nvidia` handle the making of the kernel modules.

I have done the latter on my nvidia based systems.

Comment: I don't know what's different about my system from yours, but I did that, then X wouldn't load, nouveau wouldn't work, kernel still wouldn't upgrade, so I had to remove all my (a)kmod packages from nVidia, VirtualBox, etc, boot into the rescue GRUB entry, upgrade the kernel, and now I'm on nouveau & a freshly upgraded 4.15 kernel. Crossing my fingers that I'll be able to get the nVidia drivers to work again.